# Extjs store does not fit the JSON

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I retrieve my JSON, which is :

```
{"data":[{"description":"","startDate":"2015-02-10","endDate":"[No end date]","tags":"NEW_SOURCE","value":"","name":"Lada"},{"description":"","startDate":"2015-02-10","endDate":"[No end date]","tags":"NEW_SOURCE","value":"","name":"Renault"},{"description":"Kilometrage","startDate":"2015-02-10","endDate":"2015-02-11","tags":"","value":"132","name":"Bmw"}],"success":true}
```

And I create a grid using Ext-JS this way:

```
// Bla bla 
success:function(form, action){
    var result = Ext.JSON.decode(action.response.responseText);
    createGrid(result); 
}

function createStore(result){
    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {
        fields : ['description', 'startDate', 'endDate', 'tags', 'value', 'name'], 
        autoload : true, 
        proxy : {
            type : 'memory', 
            reader : {
                type : 'json', 
                root : 'data'
            }
        }
    });
    return store; 
}


function createGrid(result){

    var store = createStore(result); 

    var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        title : "Records", 
        closable : true, 
        frame : true, 
        width : 600,
        renderTo : 'specificGridSummary', 
        store : store, 
        columns : [
          {header : 'Source',       dataIndex : 'name'}, 
          {header : 'Description',  dataIndex : 'description'},
          {header : 'Start date',   dataIndex : 'startDate'}, 
          {header : 'End date',     dataIndex : 'endDate'},
          {header : 'Value',        dataIndex : 'value'},
          {header : 'Tags',         dataIndex : 'tags'},          
        ]
    }); 

    grid.show(); 
}
```

The JSON is correct, and I checked the fileds several time. 
I also tried in **createStore**

```
 store.loadData(result)
 store.loadRaxData(result)
```

But I get exactly the same problem. 
 
**EDIT** Some lines are written with nothing, and some witth the right item. 
 
See image below 
 
[image: How to fill the missing fields?]

Do you see someone wrong with this code?

Thanks!

Comment: You haven't said what the problem us you are seeing

Comment: @kanor1306 : Indeed, my bad when copying, but this solution does not work

Comment: So can you post the correct json for us to examine?

Comment: Deleted my comment when I saw your edit. I made a fiddle, and everything work OK in the fiddle. https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/i57 Can't see right know what could be happening in your code...

Answer (score 1):

The specific problem is that you do not inject the data into your store. Add in the store :

```
data: result.data,
```

Another problem: You have `autoLoad` on a store with a memory proxy. This will have no influence (and a typo, autoload instead of autoLoad).

**The bigger picture**
You are approaching this from the wrong side. This is what you do :

- ajax request to get data
- create a store afterwards

This is how it is meant to be :

- create a store, define how it has to read the data
- have the store fetch its own data

Look into MVC and change your code like this :

```
Ext.define('App.store.Cars', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.JsonStore'
    fields : ['description', 'startDate', 'endDate', 'tags', 'value', 'name'], 
    autoLoad : true,
```

Remove autoLoad if you want to send a parameter to load the store.

```
    proxy : {
        type : 'ajax', 
        url: 'the url of your json',
        reader : {
            type : 'json', 
            root : 'data'
        }
    }
});

Ext.define('App.view.CarsGrid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.carsgrid',
    title : "Records", 
    closable : true, 
    frame : true, 
    width : 600,
    renderTo : 'specificGridSummary', 
    store : 'Cars', 
    columns : [
      {header : 'Source',       dataIndex : 'name'}, 
      {header : 'Description',  dataIndex : 'description'},
      {header : 'Start date',   dataIndex : 'startDate'}, 
      {header : 'End date',     dataIndex : 'endDate'},
      {header : 'Value',        dataIndex : 'value'},
      {header : 'Tags',         dataIndex : 'tags'},          
    ]
});
```

In the controller:

```
function createGrid(date){
    var grid = Ext.widget('carsgrid');
    grid.getStore().filter({property: 'startDate', value: date, operator: '>'})
    grid.show()
}
```

I'm not sure if you have to call store.load() or if it is done automatically.

Notice, that the store has to have an Ajax proxy to be able to load the data from the server. Notice also, that you can refer to the store as a string, once it is defined with `Ext.define`. Since the grid has an `alias`, you can also create it by name with `Ext.widget`.

For this to work you have to `requires` the classes and use `Ext.Loader`.

Comment: Well in your json there are some empty strings for the values, for example the first object for the Lada has no description set. But your grid shows a description value, are you sure you are using the same json you posted in the question?

Comment: I am. There is some empty fields, an some filled ones. But even the fields one ar not displayed in the grid.

Comment: @Lorenz Meyer : Huge Thanks! But, I have to send a date before creating the JSON. Typically : send date, create json on server, send json to client, create grid. Where can I send the date ?

Comment: If the date is a simple filter like startdate > date, you can set it as filter on the store, and it will be sent automatically. If the operation on the server is more complicated, you could send it as extraParam.

Answer (score 0):

Something you can try's setting the data property on your store to the result in the create store function

```
data: result,
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

Memory Proxy is read only, use this override to enable :

`Ext.data.MemoryProxy.override({
        updateOperation: function (operation, callback, scope) {
            console.log('updateOperation');
            operation.setCompleted();
            operation.setSuccessful();
            Ext.callback(callback, scope || this, [operation]);
        },
        create: function () {
            this.updateOperation.apply(this, arguments);
        },
        update: function () {
            this.updateOperation.apply(this, arguments);
        },
        destroy: function () {
            this.updateOperation.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    });`